# setOnLongClickListener with registerForContextMenu

Tags: java, android

I want to do some actions before show the context menu...

Is it possible to use both??

I tried:

```
name.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener()
{ 
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v)
    {
           //some code here before show the context menu

           registerForContextMenu(name);

           return true;
    }
});
```

But didn't work

thanks

EDIT: this is what i have

```
for (final File dir : dirs)
{
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

    final Button name = new Button(this);

    name.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener()
    { 
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v)
        {
               //DIR is a global variable. It saves clicked path
               DIR = dir.getAbsolutePath()+"/";

               //registerForContextMenu(name);

               return true;
        }
    });

    row.addView(name);

    fileView.addView(row);
}
```

As you can see I want to show context menu after save the path of the clicked item

Comment: In the second code snippet you set the listener for `View` `name` multiple times (once for each `dir`) which means that only the last one remains active. Why not set the appropriate `dir` as tag of the associated `View`?

Comment: How? I don't understand how to use tag

Comment: Can you put an example please?

Comment: It seems that the `name` view somehow represents the information in `dir`, right? So when creating the view call `name.setTag(dir)` and in the `OnLongClickListener` or in `onCreateContextMenu()` (where you get the view as e.g. `v`) call something like `File dir = (File) v.getTag()`

Comment: Done. App crashes. NullPointerException

Comment: I have used in onCreateContextMenu(): File dir = (File) v.getTag(); String path = dir.getAbsolutePath(); SEL_FILE = new File(path);

Comment: Show the full traceback of the exception, the full code of `onCreateContextMenu()` and mark the line where the exception occurred. Also you should show the code where you call `setTag()`

Comment: I have discovered an issue on my code so now it's finally working. setTag fixed my problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please change your answer to setTag to mark it as best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place these actions in `onCreateContextMenu()` of the activity. To react differently on different views one or more tags (arbitrary objects) can be associated with each view and read back in `onCreateContextMenu()`. The methods for this are `View.setTag()` and `View.getTag()`.

Comment: @user222 Another (but maybe not perfectly "clean") solution would be to call `registerForContextMenu(name)` in the `onCreate()`of the activity and then run the additional code in `onCreateContextMenu()`. The `OnLongClickListener` shouldn't be necessary then

Comment: I can't put in onCreate() because it's a loop that save some special info to global variables and it only must be saved before calling the context menu. The info saved is different on every item clicked.

Comment: @user222 In the `onCreateContextMenu()` method the `View` is given as parameter so the actions taken and the menu contents can differ depending on the view for which the menu was requested

Comment: The problem is the values I get in the loop are no view related.

Comment: @user222 You can associate one or more arbitrary objects to a View using `setTag()` to identify it. If this doesn't help you I need more code to understand what you mean